# get values from multidimensional arrays into one table row PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have html table with some data, and one row in that table contain all history about entry description in that row (history data is in seperate db table than main table data).

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT est.id, '|', est.date_estimate ,'|', est.description_estimate SEPARATOR '|') as description_estimate_history
```

with this DB query I'm getting all entries related to main record.

```
 $raw_data = explode("|", $this->reg['rows'][$id]['description_estimate_history']);
 $group_data = array_chunk($raw_data, 3);

 $this->reg['rows'][$id]['description_joined'] = print_r($group_data);




  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 105925
                [1] => 2013-02-28 02:14:33
                [2] => some text
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 105958
                [1] => 2013-02-28 02:14:33
                [2] => some text
            )

    )
------------------- // other row
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )
    )
----------------- // another row
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

    )
--------------- //yet another row
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 105932
                [1] => 2012-12-31 00:00:00
                [2] => some text
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 105945
                [1] => 2012-12-31 00:00:00
                [2] => some text
            )

    )
```

I can't figure out how to print this data into table rows like `date - text` ([0] is entry ID) when one row can have multiple records

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet to a better understanding on your result array

```
foreach($group_data as $dataArray){ // looping through rows
    foreach($dataArray as $array){ // looping through records     
        foreach($array as $value){ // looping through fields
          print $value."<br />";
       }
    }
}
```